# When I'm using callback in nodejs it is taking 0.1 ms in performance but when I am using same thing to promise its taking 4+ ms.why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

like:

**Using Callback**

```
import {readFile} from 'fs'
const t1 = performance.now()
readFile('./data.txt','utf-8',(err,data) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(data)
})
const t2 = performance.now()

console.log(t2-t1)
```

response time: 0.1921999454498291

**same thing using promise**

```
import {readFile} from 'node:fs/promises'

const t1 = performance.now()
try{
    const data = await readFile('./data.txt','utf-8')
    console.log(data)
}catch (err){
    console.log(err)
}
const t2 = performance.now()

console.log(t2-t1)
```

response time: 4.3973000049591064

Why using promise taking so much more time than callback.

I tried both in performace checking but found this diffrence.

Comment: The first code doesn't measure the time to read the file. Move `const t2 = performance.now(); console.log(t2-t1)` into the callback function.

Comment: `readFile('./data.txt','utf-8',(err,data) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(data)
    const t2 = performance.now();
    console.log(t2-t1);
});`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I get it. which one is actually the faster approach? using callback or promise. Yeah, I know the promise is better for maintainability and readability but which one is faster in performance?

Thank again!

Comment: There shouldn't be any big difference in performance. Use the promise if you think it's better for maintainability.

Comment: Promises are callbacks under the hood.